# How to get an specific value (with regex) of this array?

Tags: javascript, regex, cypress, sitemap

**Use case :**

This is a Cypress E2E test coded with JS and I'm trying to apply a regex filter to this array (more than 100 values) to be able to ignore everything before `/flux/sitemaps/` and catches only the .xml file names. my aim is to be able to compare pre-production and production sitemap URL contents.

One example of what I would like to achieve :

**Before regex :**

```js
[
  "https://xxxxxxxxx.com/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_cms_1.xml",
  "https://xxxxxx.com/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_category_1.xml"
]
```

**After regex (test goal) :**

```js
["/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_cms_1.xml", "/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_category_1.xml"]
```

**Or**

```js
["sitemap_cms_1.xml","sitemap_category_1.xml"]
```

I've tried different regex rules but no success so far, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [RTM](https://cypresstips.substack.com/p/parse-the-url-search-params) ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @mplungjan already tried but couldn't make it work :/

Answer (score 3):

The regex would be `/\/flux\/sitemaps\/.*/` for first match, or `/\/flux\/sitemaps\/(.*)/` with capturing group (second match).

```js
const sitemap = [
  'https://xxxxxxxxx.com/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_cms_1.xml',
  'https://xxxxxx.com/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_category_1.xml'
]

const expected1 = [
  '/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_cms_1.xml',
  '/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_category_1.xml'
]

cy.wrap(sitemap)
  .then(sm => sm.map(url => url.match(/\/flux\/sitemaps\/.*/)[0]))
  .should('deep.eq', expected1)


const expected2 = [
  'sitemap_cms_1.xml',
  'sitemap_category_1.xml'
]

cy.wrap(sitemap)
  .then(sm => sm.map(url => url.match(/\/flux\/sitemaps\/(.*)/)[1]))
  .should('deep.eq', expected2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is a string replace.

If you are dealing with a sitemap the origin part will be consistent on all URLs.

```js
cy.wrap(sitemap)
  .then(sm => sm.map(url => url.replace('https://xxxxxx.com', '')))
  .should('deep.eq', [
    '/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_cms_1.xml',
    '/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_category_1.xml'
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array populated with the results of another function on the existing array. In this case, we'll use `Array.split` to remove everything before `/flux/sitemaps`, and then use string interpolation to add the `/flux/sitemaps` back on.

```js
const origArr = ["https://xxxxxxxxx.com/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_cms_1.xml","https://xxxxxx.com/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_category_1.xml"]

const newArr = origArr.map((x) => `/flux/sitemaps${x.split('/flux/sitemaps')[1]}`);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @agoff, didn' know this one, it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a array map and a regex to remove chars from the url:

```js
const source = [
  'https://xxxxxxxxx.com/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_cms_1.xml',
  'https://xxxxxx.com/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_category_1.xml'
];
const regex = /^.*?\/flux\/sitemaps\//;
let cleaned = source.map((url) => url.replace(regex, ''));
console.log(cleaned);
```

Output:

```
[
  "sitemap_cms_1.xml",
  "sitemap_category_1.xml"
]
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- start of string
- `.*?` -- non-greedy scan, until:
- `\/flux\/sitemaps\/` -- literal `/flux/sitemaps/`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/) constructor to make parsing URLs in JavaScript a breeze and avoid the need for regex entirely!

Now you can easily compare paths between them or map again to get the files.

```js
const urls = [
      "https://xxxxxxxxx.com/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_cms_1.xml",
      "https://xxxxxx.com/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_category_1.xml"
    ];

    const paths = urls.map(url => new URL(url).pathname);

    console.log(paths);
    
    const files = paths.map(path => {
      const parts = path.split('/');
      return parts[parts.length -1];
    });
    
    console.log(files);
```

After this, if you wanted to compare two sets, you could turn one of them into a Set and then do a find on the other array to see which one wasn't in the first Set.